# Accessing an IBOutlet from another ViewController in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutlet

I'm trying to access an IBOutlet from my other view controller, I have tried importing them both;

`#import "CreateTest.h"
 #import "SecondViewController.h"`

But when I try to access the IBOutlet; `_SubjectValue.text = @"hi";`
It returns an error saying "Use of undeclared identifier _SubjectValue"

Comment: If you're trying to access one view controller IBOutlet from another view controller this is not a good practice and proper way. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344336/how-to-access-an-iboutlet-from-another-class) everything is well explained

Comment: Mine is objective-c, not swift

Comment: I know but the basic is same . And for class check out my answer bellow ..

Answer (score 0):

Make first class to delegate of second class. Then define IBOUTLET in delegate protocol. Then access it via delegate like so:

```
_delegate.yourIBOutlet.someProperty
```

If your very new I'd recommend some basic tutorials.

Edit: An instance of second class is required though. Depending if you're working with storyboard or not you ca receive/instantinate it in different ways.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to access another class IBoutlet, first you have to create object of that class.

You're trying to access  `IBOutlet` like this `_SubjectValue.text = @"hi";` which basically means `self.SubjectValue.text = @"hi";` but you'r second class don't have a IBOutlet name `SubjectValue.text`.

You have to access `IBOutlet` of another class through its object.**Create a object of the class and then use this object to access the** `property/IBOutlet` of that class

Hope it helps..

Comment: I don't know what you mean - I'm very new to iOS