# How to change outlet properties from global scope?

Tags: ios, swift

I need a function from global scope change a label on the storyboard.

When I try running this code, the error I get is:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The problem is that viewController.congratulations is null.

How to fix that? Thanks in advance!

```
func myAlert ()
{
    // how to change 'configuration.text' from here?

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
    let viewController : ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController;

    viewController.congratulations.text = "test";
}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var congratulations: UILabel!;

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        myAlert();
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: After nib load, the outlet gets the reference of the UI so it is always nil.

Comment: Here you are making again as per my understanding in `viewDidLoad` `myAlert();`

Comment: Why is `myAlert` defined outside the scope of your class?

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/28345111/5391914

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't directly try to access a `UILabel` from outside the class where it is defined. Labels are only created once `viewDidLoad` is called on the specific instance of your `UIViewController` subclass.

What you should do is store the text you want to display on your label in another variable and change that variable from outside your class.

Comment: Should I use a timer to check whether it has changed?

Comment: Definitely not. You can use property observers for this.

Answer (score 0):

The IBOutlet named `congratulations` is nil in `viewDidLoad`. So make a `String` property at `ViewController` (say stringValue). Set that string property while navigation

In your viewController's viewDidLoad method, get the stringValue and set its value to label

```
self.congratulations.text = stringValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding myAlert() into ViewController class solved the problem.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    func myAlert ()
    {
        self.congratulations.text = "vrebreberbfrbb";
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var congratulations: UILabel!;

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        myAlert();
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```