# Disable buttons of 1 view controller in another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I am having a problem when trying to disable button's user interaction of 1 view controller in another view controller.

I have searched similar questions here, but some seems outdated or does not work for me:
[How to access an IBOutlet from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344336/how-to-access-an-iboutlet-from-another-class).

My scenario is as follows:

```
class ViewControllerA() {

  @IBOutlet weak var btnFirst: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var btnSecond: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var btnThird: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    var vcB = ViewControllerB()
    vcB.closure = {
    // Meet some condition, want to disable buttons of ViewControllerA here
    }
  }

}

class ViewControllerB() {
   var closure: () -> Void = {}
   // Do something with closure here
}
```

My problem is that i set the breakpoint in the closure and try to use directly IBOulet in closure to disable buttons like:

```
btnFirst.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Or try to set a property of ViewControllerA in closure of ViewControllerB and use property observer, whenever this property changes, enable or disable buttons of ViewControllerA.

My problem is that, i can still click the buttons as if it's enable. Sorry, i cannot post the code, please help me!

Thanks

Comment: You need to post the code of what you are doing! Otherwise we won't be able to see what mistakes are you making !

Answer (score 1):

You can post notification from second view controller and add observer for that particular posted notification in first view controller.

In that observer method, you can do your stuff like disabling user interaction for first view controllers' button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post any relevant code, I can only guess what might have happened:

I assume that you are not accessing the `btnFirst` of the *correct* viewcontroller. In `ViewControllerA.viewDidLoad` you are creating an new Instance of `ViewControllerB` and set the closure. Are you also showing exactly this view controller's view? Or how will the user navigate to B? If you are using storyboard segues, those will create a new B instances and show its view. Now when you execute the closure in A, this will disable the button of the first B, not of the B that is displayed.

But this is still just a guess...